# OpenXML C# Excel SharedStringItem Inserting new line

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, office-automation

I'm using OpenXML to create a formatted block of text with Excel. The requirement is to use predefined styles (set by an admin) to format a block of text. I've managed to accomplish everything by using the **SharedStringItem** and the **Run** class. However I'm having trouble figuring out how to preserving the carriage returns "\r\n".

The following code is not producing the run on a new line

```
private static void NewRun(SharedStringItem sharedString, bool isBullet = false)
{
      var newRun = new Run();

      newRun.Text = new Text { Text = Environment.NewLine };
      sharedString.Append(newRun);
}

private static void NewRun(SharedStringItem sharedString, bool isBullet = false)
{
      var newRun = new Run();

      newRun.Text = new Text { Text = "\r\n" };
      sharedString.Append(newRun);
}
```

When the above methods are used I can see the **SharedStringItem**.InnerText is using the new lines however appear to be lost in the markup.

`<x:t>Our corporate and commercial litigation`

[image]

Have I just stumbled upon a limitation of the **SharedStringItem** or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the new line in the mark up you need to set the following property in the Text class.

```
Text { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }
```

I used the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool (definitely recommended and can be found here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5 ) to help me solve this issue.